# IN operator in check statement

Tags: abap, sap-query

In `SQ02` transaction, I want to use the check command.
Can I replace the `OR` operator with another operator, which shorts the command?
Is there an operator like `IN`, which exists in SQL?
The check command is something like:
`CHECK SKB1-BUKRS EQ '1000'` or `CHECK SKB1-BUKRS EQ '2001'` or `CHECK SKB1-BUKRS EQ '5221'` .
Is there an operator like `IN`, which exists in SQL?
`CHECK SKB1-BUKRS in ('1000', '2001', '5221')`

When I write in the Record Processing section:
START-OF-SELECTION.
  CHECK skb1-bukrs IN gt_ranges.

[image: Section Record Processing]

then I receive  ABAP error:
[image: Error message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert when it comes to `SQ02` I can see however that there are sections for `DATA` and `INITIALIZATION` so the example below should work. `IN` operator in ABAP (excluding OpenSQL of course) can only be used with ranges.

Example:

```
REPORT zzz.

DATA: gt_ranges TYPE RANGE OF bukrs.
TABLES: skb1.

INITIALIZATION.
  gt_ranges = VALUE #(
    ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = '1000' )
    ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = '2001' )
    ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = '5221' )
  ).

START-OF-SELECTION.
  CHECK skb1-bukrs IN gt_ranges.
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.                                                                               In DATA section I wrote the code gt_ranges TYPE RANGE OF bukrs. and received an error: Statement "GT_RANGES" is not defined. Check your spelling. spelling.

Comment: Try to put `DATA` keyword in front of it. Even if the section is named DATA I am not sure if it's added automatically there.

Comment: jsdfhksaj <br/>

Comment: Thanks for your replay.
I wrote DATA:  as you suggested and it helped.
When I put "START-OF-SELECTION.
  CHECK skb1-bukrs IN gt_ranges." In the START-OF-SELECTION section, then I received the message: "No data was selected" ( It should fetch records).
When I put it in "Record processing" section then I received ABAP error. I don't know how to paste the screenshot to the stack overflow comment)

Comment: Please update your question and put the screenshot there.

Comment: @hag Get rid of  `START-OF-SELECTION` keyword in "5 Record processing" section and it should work.